# can't save firebase realtime database data in java web application

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data on Firebase realetime database from Java class with a main method. But it doesn't works.I followed the instructions in firebase website, but the data of realtime database didn't update one time. And there is no error messages. I don't know why.

The rules has been set already.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The following is my code, please give some suggestions, thanks a lot!

```
public class Firebasetest {

    private static DatabaseReference database;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      // Initialize Firebase
      final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
      FirebaseApp defaultApp = null;
      try {
        // [START initialize]
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("test-firebase.json");

        FirebaseOptions options =
            new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://test.firebaseio.com")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        System.out.println("init");
        // [END initialize]
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("ERROR: invalid service account credentials. See README.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }

      try {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        ApiFuture<Void> future = database.setValueAsync("1234");
        try {
          //        future.get();
          future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        database.setValue(
            "234343",
            new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(
                  DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                latch.countDown();
              }
            });
        System.out.println("done");
        latch.await();

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you run this code in a debugger, does your `onComplete` get called? If so, does `databaseError` have a value in there?

Comment: onComplete  didn't called, and there is no error message.

Comment: Hmm.... from the way your code is structured that means the program should just sit there waiting. Is that indeed what it does? Also: does `database.setValueAsync("1234")` get written to the database?

Comment: database.setValueAsync("1234") also didn't work, and the main process is keep running until I cancel it manually.

Comment: In that case it seems the client can't connect to the database altogether. If nothing relevant is being logged right now, you might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-admin#use_slf4j_to_configure_logging) and check for relevant information on why it can't reach the server.

Comment: there is some jar missing in my project, now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem Oswin. I'm voting to close the question in that case, unless you think that the "enable debug logging" was worth an answer (in which case I'd love for you to write what you did, and what you subsequently found in the log output that allowed you to find the root case of the problem).